# pkzip and smeltwater - is my memory wrong?

Tags: command-line-arguments, pkzip

Circa 1994 I remember someone telling me with glee that an easy way to remember a certain set of command-line arguments for pkzip was to arrange them so that they spelt out `smeltwater`, or something along those lines.

Google suggests that my memory about this is not 100% accurate - can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about smeltwater, but I remember this one:

> pkzip -urp archive *.*

or

> pkzip -buurp archive *.*

(Excuse me)

Answer (score 1):

SYNOPSIS

```
 zip       [-AcdDeEfFghjklLmoqrRSTuvVwXyz@$]        [-b path]
 [-n suffixes] [-t mmddyyyy] [-tt mmddyyyy] [ zipfile [ file1
 file2 ...]]  [-xi list]
```

I think you could probably get a fair few anagrams of acdefghjklmoqrstuvwxyz

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [command line help for PKZIP and PKUNZIP](http://www.computerhope.com/software/pkutil.htm).
Maybe it'll help you recollect things.

Most of the stuff I used to do [is here](http://www.uwm.edu/~dtoth/pkzip.html).